# What backend should I use for my react-native mobile application and Laravel portal which have to use the same database?

Tags: laravel, firebase, react-native, api, scalability

I am building a mobile application in react-native. I am using Firebase for authentication and I am using Firebase cloud functions with Firestore for some API functions that get information from the Firebase database and do some calculations with them before returning them to the app.

My client also wanted a web portal where things used in the app are managed by customers. I started building this portal in Laravel, which I wanted to run in Google Cloud Run later for scalability.

My question is, should I rather have the Laravel web portal communicate with the Firebase database or should I build an API into the portal where the mobile app communicates with, and why? Or is there any other way that would be cheaper or better for scalability?

Maybe important to note that I also need to have images uploaded in the portal that are used in the app, that has to be stored somewhere.
Is it a good idea to store them in the Laravel projects storage while it runs in Google Cloud Run or will this be too expensive when scaling?

I hope someone can help me out because I am fairly new to scaling applications!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use REST Apis , but for authentication laravel uses Passport or Sanctum you are using firebase. Web portal builds in laravel may be in MySql. You can get web portal data by building larvael REST Apis. for file uploading you can use AWS. or simply move files to laravel storage dir. I suggest you to don't user Firebase if you wana make web portal , Only use Laravel and Mysql . then you need Apis for your App. Authentication goes there. and will be handled Via Passport or Sanctum.

Comment: And by doing this, the only application that could get heavy load is the whole Laravel project with the portal + API + images right? And by running this in a container in Google Cloud Run this would be solved?

Comment: The application Load Depends upon no. of Api,s Calls. Means Users Count . Crowd landing on your web right ? not App itself.

Comment: for Images I suggest AWS , upload images/files to AWS and only the file URL is stored in the data base .

Comment: In your example my react-native app is making API calls to the Laravel REST API right? So when there are a lot of users using the app and making API calls the Laravel project with the API will scale automatically when ran in Google Cloud Run right?

Comment: There is Nothing to do with laravel ,if you call a single apis thousand times it gives you response in same time. it's all about your hosting side , where you deploy you web app . if your site's traffic is heavy you should purchase a premium package . free packages are normally for testing purposes .

Comment: I mean the container where I run the Laravel application in will scale automatically based on the no. of API calls when ran in the Google Cloud Run environment right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252509/discussion-between-laurens-smid-and-sublan-mustafa).

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-instance-autoscaling You should Read this

Comment: There is an option in Laravel no. of Api Calls per minute. You can increase it.

Comment: Here it is in RouteServiceProvider.php     protected function configureRateLimiting(): void
    {
        RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(60)->by($request->user()?->id ?: $request->ip());
        });
    }

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Can I start building the portal with API locally, test on a VPS and switch to containerization and Google Cloud Run easily later? Or is it better to start the project building in a container?

Comment: You can dockerize your app later on . there is no issue . test on VPS , Later dockerize it , Thanks